# create error controller that would preserve the functionality of default error controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to implement `error controller` that would behave certain way for only single case - when it tries to display `whitelabel error page`. In other cases it should behave like the regular `BasicErrorController` that Spring Boot uses.

My current controller it seems taking over every request and even causes redirect when there is basic 401 error, despite having `restexceptionhandler`.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class ErrorPageController implements ErrorController {
    private static final String LOCALHOST_SERVER_NAME = "localhost";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorPageController.class);
    private static final String REDIRECT_FORMAT = "redirect:%s://%s%s";
    private static final String LOCALHOST_REDIRECT_FORMAT = "redirect:%s://%s:%d%s";

    @Value("${server.error.page.internalErrorPage}")
    private String internalErrorPage;

    @GetMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String handleGetError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return handleError(request);
    }

    @PutMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String handlePutError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return handleError(request);
    }

    @PostMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String handlePostError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return handleError(request);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(produces = "text/html")
    public String handleDeleteError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return handleError(request);
    }

    private String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String redirectUrl;
        if (LOCALHOST_SERVER_NAME.equals(request.getServerName())) {
            redirectUrl = String.format(LOCALHOST_REDIRECT_FORMAT, request.getScheme(), request.getServerName(),
                request.getServerPort(), internalErrorPage);
        } else {
            redirectUrl = String.format(REDIRECT_FORMAT, request.getScheme(), request.getServerName(),
                internalErrorPage);
        }

        return redirectUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

However, when I try to extend the `BasicErrorController` and it forces me to define a constructor

```
public ErrorPageController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ErrorProperties errorProperties) {
    super(errorAttributes, errorProperties);
}
```

it seems It cannot instantiate bean with error properties.

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.xxx.handler.ErrorPageController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorProperties'
```

What is the problem? What I want is just redirect when request failed and it came from `/api/oauth` URL, leaving other working as is.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is just redirect when request came from /api/oauth URL,
>   leaving other working as is.

Why don't you just define a filter?

```
@Component
public class SimpleFilter implements Filter {
   @Override
   public void destroy() {}

   @Override
   public void doFilter
      (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterchain) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {

       // do the redirect here
   }

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterconfig) throws ServletException {}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, I want to redirect when request failed on `api/oauth` endpoint. Updated a question for more clarity. Basically I want to replace the default Whitelabel Error Page with redirect.

Comment: And this is a perfect use case for a filter IMHO

Comment: Hm, but is filter involved into displaying whitelabel error page of `spring`?

Comment: No. But that's not what you want

Comment: I tried but it seems I cannot get required attributes in filter. In `BasicErrorController` in debug I can access them but in my own filter it seems they are not available.

Comment: Which attributes?

Comment: `javax.servlet.error.request_uri` or `javax.servlet.error.status_code`. Inside `errorHtml` of BasicErrorController I have them

Comment: If they exist they are accessible through req.getAttribute(
                  "javax.servlet.error.status_code");

Comment: no, there is none. Probably because `error controller` wraps stuff and stores it somewhere deep or something in request. As it returns ModelAndView from controller then it might be somewhere...

Comment: No this is not Spring specific. javax comes from Java EE and is availible in every servlet contaner like Tomcat

Comment: Well, maybe it is just buried deep. Oh, it seems like my filter works earlier than `errorHtml`.